# Paint like Feature in Web.Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, paint

i want to implement Ms Paint like feature in my web application in c# asp.net. like cropping coloring zooming ,color picker etc . Please tell me is there any pre build tools or application for it.Any pointers and suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use jquery plugin....

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-image-crop-plugin-jcrop/

http://www.webappers.com/2008/09/12/jcrop-poweerful-image-cropping-engine-for-jquery/

Answer (score 2):

If your looking for C#, your only option is **Silverlight**.

If you can do something other than C#, theres **Adobe Flash**, as well as some **JavaScript**.  JavaScript can be limited (though I have seen some pretty nice ones) when it comes to graphics, unless you want to use the **Canvas tag**.  The only problem with the Canvas tag and JS is that it is not fully supported in all browsers yet.